# Android Firebase - Can't receive proper JSON from Firebase snapshot

Tags: java, android, json, encoding, firebase

My android app connects to Firebase and pulls "Alert Objects" that are sent there by my server.

When I export the data from Firebase, I get a beautifully formated JSON representation of the data.

Problem:
When I pull the data to my android device using a DataSnapshot, the data has '=' (equals signs) instead of ':' (semicolons). Also the quotations are not there.

When I try to do something like `JSONObject alert = new JSONObject(data.getValue().toString());` I get errors for obvious reasons. I say obvious because if you look at what my code prints to the console you can see that it is no longer in valid JSON format.

A friend mentioned that I need to do something with encoding but we didn't have time to discuss it.

How can I iterate through these (kinda weird) Alert Objects that I have created and turn them into JSON objects within my Java so that I can access their properties like `alert.date` and `alert.message`.

I thought screenshots would help you see what I am doing. The firebase is not secured at all so you can feel free to take a look at it. It won't really do much and when I go to production I will be moving it anyways.

[image: Firebase screenshot]

[image: JSON export straight from Firebase website]

[image: Code in Android Studio to print each object to console]

[image: Output to console when running app]

I am sure this is a super easy question to answer, I am just not too well versed with JSON and encoding as a whole.

Thanks!

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing(tm) to do.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen That is a screenshot of the Firebase exported text. I am on my phone right now but when I get home I will load the searchable text. What you see there is 99% of it though. It's only a few more lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot access JSON natively in Java.

But the [Firebase `DataSnapshot` class](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/datasnapshot/) provides everything you need.

If you have a `DataSnapshot` of the data at  the `fbAlerts` in your screenshot, you can print the date+message and recipients for each:

```
for (DataSnapshot alert: alerts.getChildren()) {
  System.out.println(alert.child("date").getValue();
  System.out.println(alert.child("message").getValue();
  for (DataSnapshot recipient: alert.child("recipients").getChildren()) {
    System.out.println(recipient.child("name").getValue();
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can build a Java class that represents an alert. See the [Firebase guide on reading data in Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) for examples of that.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for my late reply. I ended up figuring this out almost immediately after posting the question. Well, I already knew for the most part, I was just hoping there was an easier way. My code now is a bit...crude?... but it gets each child using these for loops and builds my objects properly. Thanks again!

Comment: @Frank link is broken.

Comment: Updated. Thanks for flagging.

Answer (score 7):

you can it using gson library

```
       public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            /*JSONObject jsonObject = null;
            try {
                jsonObject=new JSONObject();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String s1 = gson.toJson(dataSnapshot.getValue());
            JSONArray object = null;
            try {
                object = new JSONArray(s1);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            JSONArray jsonArray = object;

            Log.e("string", s1);

        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Use this way to convert the jsonObject form the dataSnapshot

```java
Map<String, String> value = (Map<String, String>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
Log.i("dataSnapshot", "dataSnapshot" + new JSONObject(value));
```

Comment: How can we convert it back to Datasnapshot?

Answer (score 0):

From the above code extract, it looks like you have a JSONArray rather than a JSONObject.

In which case, you need to do something like the following:

```
// Find the right array object
JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("fbAlerts"); 

// Loop through the array
for (int i=0; i< jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject myObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i); 
    strMsg = myObj.getString("message");
}
```

In the example - when you have repeating groups, this would seem to indicate an array and therefore needs an iterator to access the object contents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up just looping through the child of each parent, a few 'children' deep actually and built my objects manually.