# How to get object in jsonarray firebase android?

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Structure Firebase data

[image: Structure Firebase data]

[DetailItemOrderSetGet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQj26.png)

I want to get all data in order_detail or one of data inside order_detail like detail_item_id. I always get error force close because order_detail, but how to make looping for that or How is to get one of array object? I just can get for data with one level like order_customer_name or order_date. this is my code. thanks

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            processOrderList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    DetailitemOrderSetGet orderDetail = postSnapshot.child("order_detail").getValue(DetailitemOrderSetGet.class);
                        processOrderList.add(postSnapshot.getValue(OrderHistorySetGet.class));

                }
            processAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: please share your class `DetailitemOrderSetGet ` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `JSONArray` in order to get data from a Firebase database. You can just iterate over the `DataSnapshot` object using `getChildren()` method. Assuming that the `Transaction` node is a direct child of your Firebase database root and you are storing the `detail_item_id` as an `int`, to get the value of your `detail_item_id` from all childrens under `order_detail` node, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference orderDetailRef = rootRef.child("Transaction").child("4").child("order_detail");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            int detail_item_id = ds.child("detail_item_id").getValue(Integer.class);
            Log.d("TAG", detail_item_id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
orderDetailRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: thank you for helping. But I think that's only for get data order detail from transactions where child = 4. How about the others child?

Comment: okay, I understand what you meant. But I think if I use your code. I can't get the data under root. But I have earned my answer in this link [firebase nested get data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37091468/android-firebase-cant-receive-proper-json-from-firebase-snapshot). overall, Thank you very much Alex

Comment: You're welcome. Did you think that my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not know what is the Setter getter of you class **DetailitemOrderSetGet**. But I would talk about its general pattern.Do not confuse yourself with the Json object and Json Array.  This Firebase data return is in Json format and that is really very simple and fast to execute.

I will talk about its general pattern using your Json return.

The First thing that I can see is Json Array in your return namely **Transactions**

first of all get it and store it. for an instance look below

```
JSONArray transactionsArray = myFirebaseReturnOBJECT.get("Transactions");
```

Now that you have got the array in your transactionsArray . Now you need to loop through it to get your required Data.

Now the second step is to get another data segment which is also a JSONArray so we have to do same procedure but in for loop since we have our TransactionsArray.

```
for (int i = 0; i<transactionsArray.length();i++){
            JSONArray orderDetailsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("order_details");

            for (int j = 0; j <orderDetailsArray.length() ; j++) {
                JSONObject order_detail_OBJ = orderDetailsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                String detail_item_id  = order_detail_OBJ.getString("detail_item_id");
            }

        }
```

You can see that I have managed to do the 2 for loops since that there is 2 jsonArrays. so in step 2 have used for loop and got the JsonObject at index "j" and from that JsonObject namely  **order_detail_OBJ** i have successfully gotten my desired field that is detail_item_id

I hope this will help you in getting what you are looking for.I have just put up this as example there could be some type mistakes.

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't understand how you declare the Transactions from firebase to jsonArray.

Comment: what is the confusion now